# Как правильно организовать поиск файла с определенным расширением

Tags: php

Здравствуйте! Нужна помощь! Пишу программу которая по всему диску(Windows), должен найти файлы с расширением ini. 
Как ни странно я код пишу на PHP, это главное..
Вот код:

```
class ReadableFilter extends RecursiveFilterIterator{   
  public function accept(){     
          return $this->current()->isReadable();
  }
}

function Search($dir, $ext){
  $iterator = new ReadableFilter(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($dir));
  $iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator( $iterator );
  $filter = new RegexIterator($iterator, '/^.+\.(?:'.$ext.')$/i',  RecursiveRegexIterator::GET_MATCH);
  $filelist = array();
  foreach($filter as $entry) {
    $filelist[] = $entry[0];
  }

  return $filelist;
}
```

Ну и вот, надо как то сделать, чтобы код работал быстро, а то ждать 10-15, а то и 30 мин не резонно, не знаю может сделать какое-то ограничение на размер файла, или что то другое.. И еще кто разбирается этим классом, как можно ограничить определенные папки, чтобы он не искал!
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Не используйте regexp там, где можно обойтись строковыми функциями. Ну и сдается мне, грамотно написанный нативный код будет работать еще в несколько раз быстрее.

Comment: быстро? имхо - вы просите невозможного. сотни тысяч, миллионы файлов перебрать за пару минут невозможно. даже встроенные средства ОС не дадут вам такой возможности. еще скажите, что у вас HDD )) но если вы сузите круг поиска до пары сотен, а лучше - десятков тысяч файлов - то другой разговор.

Answer (score 1):

Наверное так для windows

```
$bufer = array();
exec('find /I D:\\*.ini',$bufer);
var_dump($bufer);
```